# Dynamic self referencing many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic, many-to-many, relationship

How to construct dynamic self referencing many-to-many relationship ?

I have a problem that i cannot overcome.

I have tables:

```
Types:
id
name

Products:
id
name
type_id

product_products
parent_id
child_id
```

Let's assume that we have several products in Product table. Some of them are:
(Name is not relevant)

```
CB1234 - products.type_id -> cardboard
CBB999 - products.type_id -> cardboardbox
CBP321 - products.type_id -> paper

TSH123 - products.type_id -> tshirt
FAB321 - products.type_id -> fabric
THR321 - products.type_id -> thread
```

Now i want to tell that product_product relationship that i have cardboardbox that is made of cardboard and paper types of products. In cardboardbox-cardboard and cardboardbox-paper relationship i want to define how much percentage of product is used (consistency) to make cardboardbox product(lets say 80/20, not relevant)

I have different cases for different products. Now i want to define relationship between tshirt-fabric and tshirt-thread but instead of consistency i want to define fabric and thread cost for this product.

Products and product parameters count is not fixed. There could be 500 different products and different relations between them. What are good practices for this problem? There are few ways that i came up with

1. Lots of handmade many-to-many relationship tables
2. Lots and lots of columns to product_product table

In both cases there are things i don't like in design, but maybe those are correct way to do that and maybe i have designed my database wrong from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) would be the way to go - not sure there would really be "lots" once you worked out everything you wanted to store

product_product_consistency
product_product_cost (could this instead be represented as product_cost, then calculated from product_product_consistency or some such?)

What is the final usage, what kind of questions do you want to ask the data?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think that you might be right. 
"What is the final usage, what kind of questions do you want to ask the data?" - Answer is all of them. I don't know the amount or what type questions might come in the future. That's why i need it to be as dynamic as possible.

Comment: A very generic option would be something like a product_relationship table with a relationship_type, but I think using one table for lots of relationships is antithetical to the way relational databases work, and is just storing up trouble. A clear purpose for each table (either an "object" or a relationship between objects) is the way to do things.